# How to provide updated 'seq' package to magit?

Tags: init-file, magit, echo-area

Recently I installed Debian (so I rewrote my emacs configuration file).
I usually like to use [use-package](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package), because it makes the installation of packages simple.

This is how I fetched magit from melpa:

```
(use-package magit
  :ensure t)
```

This is all well and fine until I restarted emacs.
I get a pretty big error log:

```
Emergency (magit): Magit requires ‘seq’ >= 2.24,
but due to bad defaults, Emacs’ package manager, refuses to
upgrade this and other built-in packages to higher releases
from GNU Elpa.

To fix this, you have to add this to your init file:

  (setq package-install-upgrade-built-in t)

Then evaluate that expression by placing the cursor after it
and typing C-x C-e.

Once you have done that, you have to explicitly upgrade ‘seq’:

  M-x package-install seq \‘RET’

Then you also must make sure the updated version is loaded,
by evaluating this form:

  (progn (unload-feature 'seq t) (require 'seq))

If this does not work, then try uninstalling Magit and all of its
dependencies.  After that exit and restart Emacs, and only then
reinstalling Magit.

If you don’t use the ‘package’ package manager but still get
this warning, then your chosen package manager likely has a
similar defect. Disable showing Disable logging
Emergency (transient): Transient requires ‘seq’ >= 2.24,
but due to bad defaults, Emacs’ package manager, refuses to
upgrade this and other built-in packages to higher releases
from GNU Elpa, when a package specifies that this is needed.

To fix this, you have to add this to your init file:

  (setq package-install-upgrade-built-in t)

Then evaluate that expression by placing the cursor after it
and typing C-x C-e.

Once you have done that, you have to explicitly upgrade ‘seq’:

  M-x package-upgrade seq \‘RET’

Then you also must make sure the updated version is loaded,
by evaluating this form:

  (progn (unload-feature ’seq t) (require ’seq))

Until you do this, you will get random errors about ‘seq-keep’
being undefined while using Transient.

If you don’t use the ‘package’ package manager but still get
this warning, then your chosen package manager likely has a
similar defect. Disable showing Disable logging
```

As it says in the warning, I added this to my emacs config:

```
  (setq package-install-upgrade-built-in t)
```

... evaluated the expression with *C-x C-e* and I see `t` in the echo-area. So I figure that probably indicates success.
However, I can't follow up with installing the seq package, as there is nothing of the like in the melpa repository.

I want to get rid of this error log and provide all new packages to magit.
How do I fix this?
I found this relevant discussion on the topic, but it didn't enlighten me either:
https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/5011

Comment: In my Emacs 29.2, `seq` 2.24 is a builtin package. I build my Emacs from the source myself to always have access to the most recent magit.

Comment: @choroba Well I build it with the package manager. My version is 28.2. So what is the best course of action? Wait until the debian maintainers update emacs? Or build emacs from source as you did? Or update the standalone seq package?

Comment: Building emacs from source is not that hard. I basically just untar it, run `./config --prefix=/usr/local --with-x`, `make`, and `sudo make install`.

Comment: ok I will consider doing that. Thanks!

Comment: Albeit I am not sure why you use /usr/local instead of /usr/local/bin?

Comment: Executables are installed to `/usr/local/bin/`, but other stuff goes to `/usr/local/lib`, `/usr/local/share`, `/usr/local/man` etc.

Comment: "there is nothing of the like in the melpa repository" -- it's not in MELPA; it's in the (default) GNU ELPA archive.  Use `M-x package-refresh-contents` if you didn't already, and then `M-x list-packages` and `/ n seq` to filter by name.  `i` to mark for installation, and `x` to execute your marked changes.

Comment: @phils Oh cool. I followed your instructions and it actually works. I was not aware that packages could be installed that way. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @phils Post has been undeleted. Sorry. I thought the post is not well written. (therefore I decided to delete it)

Comment: Cheers.  It's actually a *good* question -- it has all the necessary quotations, and the details of what you tried.  As my comment did the trick, I've converted that into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update the core `seq` package from the default GNU ELPA package archive:

- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `package-refresh-contents`
- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `list-packages`
- <kbd>/</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> `seq` to filter by name.
- <kbd>i</kbd> to mark a package for installation.
- <kbd>x</kbd> to execute your marked changes.

You should have version 2.24 or later available this way.